# C++ Template Restriction on having a method

Tags: c++, templates, restriction

I want to learn whether there is a way to restrict templates such that instances have a specific method. For example, think of a generic isLess function which needs operator< or operator>. Is there a way to control that?

```
template <Class T>
bool isLess(T first,T second){ return first < second; }
```

When we use this with a class not having operator< it will give an error. How can I deal with it?

Comment: The compiler imposes the restriction: if `T` does not have a valid `operator <` then the code won't compile (although the error might be non-trivial to decipher).

Comment: Apart from the improper `Class` tag, you're essentially replicating `std::less<>`. Reinventing that wheel seems a little overkill.

Answer (score 2):

SFINAE and [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) can help you:

```
// enabled only if first<second is valid
template <class T>
auto isLess(T first,T second)
-> typename std::enable_if< (sizeof(first<second)>0), bool>::type
{ return first < second; }
```

or to allow the reverse as well, use

```
template< class T, class = void >
struct has_less_than
  : std::false_type {};

template< class T >
struct has_less_than< T, typename std::enable_if< (sizeof(
  std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>() // the expression to test
)>0) >::type >
  : std::true_type {};
```

and use it like this

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if< has_less_than<T>::value, bool>::type
isLess(T first,T second) { return first < second; }

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if< !has_less_than<T>::value, bool>::type
isLess(T first,T second) { return second > first; }
```

Comment: There is no need for the gratuitous `enable_if<EXPR, ...>` if `EXPR` is already a substitution failure. For the first example, just use `template <class T, class = decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>()) > bool isLess(...) { ...}`.